# For each div, hide previous element if its children are all hidden?

Tags: jquery, each

I have a filtered list with dividers similar to this link. I have mine working exactly the same as the example except the dividers aren't hidden when their contents are empty, which is what i'm trying to achieve.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/lists-search-with-dividers.html

The first block of code in the keyup event works to filter the list, but it breaks when I add the 2nd block.

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    $(".filtered:first li").each(function () {

        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {

            $(this).addClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden");
            count++;
        }

    });

    //code i've added
    $('.li-group').each(function(){
        if($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) {
           $(this).prev().css('display','none');
        }
    }):

});
```

My HTML has this structure:

```
<li class="divider">A</li>
<div class="li-group">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</div>

<li class="divider">B</li>
<div class="li-group">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</div>
```

What I was trying to do with my code was, on each keyup event, check if all the children of `div.li-group` are hidden, and if so then hide the previous element which is the list's divider.

Note, I know my code is currently unsemantic, but I want to get my demo working before I go back and clean up the code.

Comment: I think you code just works fine http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/19/

Comment: Not when I add the keyup event: http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/C5vKM/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/C5vKM) you given in comment contains an error in the jquery code:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    $('.li-group').each(function(){
        if($(this).children(':visible').length == 0) {
           $(this).prev().css('display','none');
        }
    }):
      ^ should be ; 
});
```

I correct the error and its just fine

**[Corrected Code](http://jsfiddle.net/C5vKM/1/)**